# Cannot access Ubuntu when I leave it alone for a while

Tags: 12.04, dell

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. Dual-boot with Windows 7.
64bit
Everything works fine.

The problem is that, I run some python code in ubuntu. And I left it alone.
When I came back, there is not input to the screen.
I just click the mouse and keyboard, there's no response.

But the desktop light is on.

For now, I can only press the power button on the desktop to turn computer on, and press the power button again to start the computer.

It happened twice. So how can I solve the problem.

If I leave just a short time, I can access the ubuntu system.
If I leave a long time, like more than 8 hours, there is no input to the screen. And I am not sure whether the ubuntu is working or not. The system is not responding.

Comment: Are you using a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: I am using a dell desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open Dash and search for **Brightness and lock**
- In the window, set **screen off when inactive** for to ***never***
  [image: image of Brightness and lock]

Comment: Thanks so much!
Another question, when the screen was off, how can I active the screen.
I'm using the desktop.

Comment: @Cindy use the same button you use to start the laptop(i.e the power button, or whatever people call it).

Comment: Thanks~ Although I press the power button, and the computer shutdown.

Comment: found this in man page **pm-suspend
           During suspend most devices are shutdown, and system state is saved in RAM. The system still requires power in this state. Most modern systems require 3 to 5 seconds to enter and leave suspend, and most laptops can stay in suspend mode for 1 to 3 days before exhausting their battery**